# Qt fails to find codec plugin

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I downloaded and installed the prebuilt Qt 4.7.4 binaries on Windows XP.

Then I compiled (using Visual Studio 2010) and ran (using the Visual Studio 2010 debugger) a program with the line

```
QTextCodec* codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("EUC-JP");
```

The returned pointer is null. What might the error be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. When I ran the app, it loaded the Qt binaries in *C:/Program Files/TortoiseHg* instead of the binaries in *C:/Qt/4.7.4/bin*. After I removed *C:/Program Files/TortoiseHg* from the system PATH variable, everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking what the [library paths](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths) are set to:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
qDebug() << app.libraryPaths();
```

Check any of the reported directories. I'm running Mac and mine reside in "/Developer/Applications/Qt/plugins" which is in the path. (*Note that the codecs themselves reside in a sub directory called "codecs".*)

If you know where they are try adding them:

```
QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath("/the/path/to/the/plugins");
```